# Get metrics that are exposed using REST API's into Prometheus

Tags: python, go, prometheus, datadog

For instance am trying to get the connected user count from [this API](https://pan.dev/access/docs/insights/examples/mobile-users-dashboard/connected-user-count/)

The return json looks like,
[image]

If I want to grab the user_count and send it to data visualization platform like datadog or prometheus, is writing a custom exporter that polls at a certain interval and grabs the value, converts it to a metric(like gauge or counter) the only option to accomplish this?

Or is there a better way to do this integration that I might be missing?

Comment: Not sure why there is a negative vote on this question?

Comment: "Is writing a custom exporter that polls at a certain interval and grabs the value [...] the only option to accomplish this?" Pretty much. But don't poll on your own interval if you can help it. [Getting up-to-date data for every scrape is preferrable](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#scheduling). In Go, it boils down to implementing the [Collector interface](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector) and then registering an instance of the Collector.